# How to change default file extensions from .arb to .rb in VS Code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, file-extension

Learning ruby using Visual Studio Code as my primary IDE.

VSC defaults my ruby files to save as .arb rather than .rb
My mentor has asked that I change this, but it has to be done manually each time I save a file. I've read this answer [What are the differences between .rb and .arb files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69471158/what-are-the-differences-between-rb-and-arb-files) but it doesn't give any clue of how to change this. (I understand that there's functionally no difference at this stage but it's annoying).

Does anyone know how to change the default file extension for a given language?

Comment: Do you know what extensions you have enabled in vsc? I don't have this problem (although I do code on Linux)

Comment: how do you create the file? Use the `New File` button in View top menu (rectangle with a +) in the Explorer View and name your file `myfile.rb`, then you don't have to select a language, VSC will do that for you, or use context menu of Explorer View

Comment: @Jad I have Ruby, Ruby Debug, VSCode Ruby and Code Builder enabled. I'll disable and see if any of these are causing the problem, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @rioV8 I'm now using `New File` and `Save As` to save manually as `myfile.rb` before I start coding - takes a bit extra time though. If I click `Save` only it puts the .arb extension. Not life or death but annoying when I forget.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone sees this in the future. The issue I had was with this extension:
https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby

Disabling it got me back to *.rb by default.